# ERROR : System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception, unhandled

If i try this  :

```
int count = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count) ? count : default(int);
```

instead of this : `int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

problem is solved but then it gives an Array out of range error. 
    What should i do ?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Player
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string[] inputs;

        // game loop
        while (true)
        {
            int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // The number of current enemy ships within range
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Count:" + count);

            Enemy[] enemys = new Enemy[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                enemys[i] = new Enemy(inputs[0], int.Parse(inputs[1]));
            }

            Array.Sort(enemys, delegate(Enemy en1, Enemy en2) {
                    return en1.Dist.CompareTo(en2.Dist);
                  });

            Console.WriteLine(enemys[0].Name);
        }
    }
}


public class Enemy{
    public string Name;
    public int Dist;

    public Enemy(string name, int dist){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Dist = dist;
    }   
}
```

Comment: At least say where the error occurs for a start, I'd image you are getting no results for `inputs` you should check this has 2 values

Comment: My first problem is "Input string was not in the correct format" for int count. I tried to solve with TryParse method. However it gives another error  for the line     "Console.WriteLine(enemys[0].Name);"   and it was
"Array index is out of range.
at Player"

Comment: Please improve your question and question title. Where did the exception exactly occurse? What do you have already changed in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This can call an "Array out of range" exception, if your input string does not contains a white space:

```
inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
enemys[i] = new Enemy(inputs[0], int.Parse(inputs[1]));
```

You should also check, wether `count` is greater equal *0*, becuase if it smaller than *0*, you try to create an array with a wrong size,

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse` will return False if it fails to parse the input as well as setting the value of `count` to 0, this means you then create an array of 0 length, but try to access the first element of this array which doesn't exist

```
enemys[0].Name; // This won't exist because enemy's list is empty
```

To start with you should make the user enter a correct value.

```
int count;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value! Try Again");
}
```

Comment: I guess he needs to parse `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')[1]` since that is what OP is doing in the loop.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `string[]'

Comment: This is a codingame.com project. I don't know whether it's about their compiler or not , but it gives an Unexpected {  error right now. Geez...
This is the project : 
http://www.codingame.com/ide/1020344fffa484480200e7a01eaf8365b1412c1

Onboarding puzzle.

Comment: @NecatiTuran  - As well as checking this value you should be checking that the split inside the loop contains 2 values (`inputs.Length >= 2`), You may need other error checking also

Comment: Also, as @TimSchmelter mentioned (cheers), you will need to also check that the second split is indeed a valid integer (Hint: you can use try parse again)